# How to add GIT and GITHUB as safe applications to Bit Defender

Tags: windows-10, git, bitdefender

I use BIT DEFENDER internet security 2016

When I'm trying to commit/push/pull/fetch/other I get told Bit Defender has blocked it. I need to be able to mark GIT as safe (to white list it)

Searching on Google shows me how to white list websites but not applications..

Under the ransomware section I can add programs. Mine currently looks like (and this is only part of the list)

[image]

As you can see, multiple git.exe

How do I add all of the GIT, GitHub and associated .exe to the allowed list because looking at the list, it appears as if the app resides in the `appdata` folder and appears to generate a unique string for the folder. I suspect BitDefender is trusting applications by the path, not the name of the application (which makes sense)

Comment: Add the applications folder as an exception

Comment: Try to exclude the folder  `c:\users\dave\appdata\local\github` as described in [How do I exclude a folder from being scanned](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-from-being-scanned-[bitdefender-windows-8-security]-1067.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first described in the comment above,
try to exclude the folder `c:\users\dave\appdata\local\github` from scanning.

From the article [How do I exclude a folder from being scanned](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-from-being-scanned-[bitdefender-windows-8-security]-1067.html) :

> 1. Open the Bitdefender window.
> 2. Click the **Settings** button on the upper toolbar.
> 3. In the **Settings Overview** window, select **Antivirus**.
> 4. In the **Antivirus Settings** window, select the **Exclusions** tab.
> 5. Make sure **Exclusions for files** is turned on by clicking the switch.
> 6. Click the **Excluded files and folders** link.
> 7. Click the **Add** button, located at the top of the exclusions table.
> 8. Click **Browse**, select the folder that you want to be excluded from scanning and then click **OK**.
> 9. Click **Add** and then click **OK** to save the changes and close the window.

Comment: I noticed that you added the link quickly... I also tested it then but GIT did not update since then (typical). Thank you

Answer (score 4):

On the BitDefender [website](http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-add-exclusions-(exceptions)-in-bitdefender-2015-1307.html), it tells you how to exclude files and folders from being scanned. This same page tells you how to add firewall rules for specific applications. I'd suggest adding the folder "C:\Users\Dave\appdata\local\github" to your exclusions.

Comment: This was already proposed in the comments.

Comment: @harrymc You could have written your own answer based on your comment. You chose not to.

Comment: @harrymc, it's people like you that -really- make me wish that comments have downvotes. DAMN!

Answer (score 0):

Search for this path `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` and add to trusted path